# How to make all axis ticks face inwards in ggplot2 including secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, axis

For aesthetic purposes I'd like to have all my axis ticks face inwards instead of outwards including the axis ticks of the secondary axis whilst keeping the secondary axis value blank. I'm able to do it for all my axis (see code), however, is there a way to keep my secondary axis values "blank" instead of a duplication?

```
ggplot(matrix, aes(x)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = bn0.5), linetype = "solid") +
  geom_line(aes(y = bn0.7), linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_line(aes(y = bn0.9), linetype = "twodash") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.1),
                     sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.01, 0.06, 0.02),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 1, breaks = seq(0.01, 0.06, 0.02), )) +
  xlab("1 - d") +
  ylab("macroHR(loo)") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'dashed', colour = "grey90"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'dashed', colour = "grey90"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'grey20'),
        axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.25, "cm"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")))
```

Right now, I did a workaround and I've set my secondary axis as a duplicate of my x and y axis. But now, I need to remove my secondary axis values, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I found the solution already by using axis.text.y.right = element_blank() and similarly for x.top